# Tag merge request: [source-control], [vcs] into [version-control] on SO

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

`[version-control]` -  2166 questions

<strike>`[source-control]` -  106 questions</strike>
<strike>`[vcs]` -  62 questions (Except the ones also tagged with `[verilog]` -- see below)</strike> (Completed Mar 29/2010)
<strike>`[revision-control]` -  6 questions</strike>
<strike>`[source]` AND `[control]` -  14 questions</strike>
<strike>`[version]` AND `[control]` - 21 questions (some overlap with previous)</strike>

I manually retagged 3 of the 12 questions marked with `[rcs]`, ones that do not specifically refer to RCS, an old piece of revision control software.

I also retagged the single question with `[revision]` AND `[control]`.

**UPDATE:** Someone has been busy, thank you. Updated the counts and manually retagged the 6 `[revision-control]` questions.

**Edit:** [VCS](http://www.synopsys.com/tools/verification/functionalverification/pages/vcs.aspx) is a [Verilog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog) simulator, so `[vcs]` unfortunately needs to remain in the system. There are currently only 3 questions tagged with both `[vcs]` and `[verilog]`, so hopefully new questions about version control realize that `[vcs]` (3) might not be the right tag for such a common topic.

Comment: oh come on, you can retag the other 185 questions :)

Comment: @earlz: I'm not opposed to doing it, if it will get the mods' attention. I started on one of my other requests (# Q's = ~120), but a diamond mod saw what I was doing and finished the job while I was still working.

Comment: "old piece"  Sure, it's old, but still damn useful.  Just sayin'...

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard Where do they use it, at museums? :)

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: I see your smiley, but just for those who are wondering: RCS doesn't need *any* setup, and you don't have to put all the files in one directory in the same repo (because there is none).  So, it can still be useful.  Oh, and you don't need distributed versioning for everything (although I love DVCSes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have completed this request by hand.